# Sqoop: How to add an extra column with default non-null value during import to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have an SQL table with the following columns:

```
title, author, genre, rating
```

On import from SQL to CSV file into HDFS with Sqoop I need to add an extra **non-null** column `src` that has a default value "online" for every input record.
How to do this in Sqoop?
So a resulting record should have the following format:

```
src, title, author, genre, rating
```

where `src` = "online" for every output record

Answer (score 1):

As I found the following SQL in Sqoop creates additional column with non-null default value `im`:

```
sqoop --query "select 'online' as src, title, author, genre, rating from table AND \$CONDITIONS" --map-column-java src=String --target-dir /data/input
```

Answer (score 0):

In sqoop directly we can't get default value like that. May be in sqoop query we can give SQL command. I can suggest alternate way .

First import the table as it is and do following transformation

A = load sample.csv using PigStorage(',') as (title, author, genre, rating);

B = foreach A generate 'online' as source, *;

store B into 'some location' using PigStorage(',');

It will give online column in each row as a default value..It will fulfill your requirement